# Find any inntertext have custom prefix HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have list name files html like this :

```
<tr>
<td>ABC.rar</td>
<td>XYZ.zip</td>
<td>DEF.MP4</td>
</tr>
```

How i can find file ABC.rar just add prefix ABC

```
string innerText = document2.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//td[2]//a[.='ABC']").InnerText;
```

Comment: your regex should be `/([A-Z]+\.rar)/g`

Comment: @shayanypn That's not Regex, it's XPATH.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't clear why there is `a` in your attempted XPath while there is no `<a>` element in the sample HTML. Anyway, the following are two possible XPath to find `<td>` that contains keyword `'ABC'` :

```
//td[contains(.,'ABC')]
//td[starts-with(.,'ABC')]
```

Difference between the two should be self-explanatory given a clear function names being used. If I understand what you mean by *prefix* correctly, I suspect `starts-with()` would be more appropriate here compared to `contains()`.

---

**Demo :**

```
var html = @"<tr>
<td>ABC.rar</td>
<td>XYZ.zip</td>
<td>DEF.MP4</td>
</tr>";

var document2 = new HtmlDocument();
document2.LoadHtml(html);
string innerText = document2.DocumentNode
                            .SelectSingleNode("//td[starts-with(.,'ABC')]")
                            .InnerText;
Console.WriteLine(innerText);
```

**<kbd>[`dotnetfiddle demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WYzcRS)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
ABC.rar
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj `.` references current context node, in this case the `td`, which when used in a string operation such as in `contains()` or `starts-with()` function, the context node will be implicitly converted to string as if `string()` function was called

Comment: after i add your code , it show error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @HuongPham that means your HTML is different from the one posted. See the demo, it should've worked.